# PHP Both kinds of quotes in variables

Tags: php

I used to know this, but I guess it slipped my mind.
What's the code you put in the beginning and the end of a variable in php to allow both kind of quotes?

Comment: Read http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The personal rules I follow (not a silver bullet):

1. If there is no single quotes in the string - use `'`
2. If there is single quote(s) in the string - use `"`
3. If there are different types of quotes in the string - use `'` or [HEREDOC](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: @xdazz: no wondering - it is obvious :-) and I bet any developer sooner or later comes to something very similar :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are thinking of [heredocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Example:

```
echo <<<EOT
Some text here '' ""'
This should print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
```